# Integrating standalone WiFi chip (TI CC3100) into Linux

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm considering using a TI CC3100 WiFi chip with a SoC running Linux.
As far as I know, there is no native driver for Linux supporting CC3100. Furthermore, the interface to CC3100 is SPI or UART (not SDIO or USB).

Does anyone know of driver support for such a WiFi device in Linux?

Comment: You should ask this question on http://superuser.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is an unofficial driver on github: [Patch to run wlan module TI cc3100boost on linux](https://github.com/rpricken/cc3100-linux)